# Random 2d array isn't being printed

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, random

```
public class Alfabhto {

int[][] pinakas = new int[3][6];
String[] gramata ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an alphanumeric combination");
    String fail = s.nextLine();

    System.out.println(pinakas[i][j]);

}

    public int[][] Numbers() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            pinakas[i][j] = rand.nextInt(38)-12;
        }
    }
    return pinakas;

}
}
```

First of all, I am very new at java. The main function works properly and the user is asked to give an input. Some elements aren't used here (like the gramata array) so ignore them.

The problem is: the method numbers should fill the pinakas array with random numbers and then print them. It does nothing if it's in the method. Outside it brings up errors because it can't get "pinakas" array or i and j. Any ideas?

Comment: You never actually create a `Numbers`, so the constructor is never called.

Comment: ...and if you did, you'd get a `NoSuchElementException` when `j = 6`. Your loops need to use `<`, not `<=`.

Comment: ...and don't re-create the `Random` object on each iteration of the inner loop. Create it *once*, and reuse it.

Comment: add this to your main method where you want the code in constructor to be called: `new Numbers();` This creates a new instance of the `Numbers` class with no reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is several issues with that code, see comments:

```
// Need to import Random
import java.util.Random;

public class Alfabhto {

    String[] gramata ={"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    // This neesd to be final for Numbers to access it
    final int[][] pinakas = new int[3][6];

    // There's no reason for Numbers to be public, or to extend Alfabhto, or in
    // fact to be a class at all. Recommend making it a static method within
    // Alfabhto (in which case gramata and pinakas must also be static), or an
    // instance method if appropriate (in which case pinaka does not need to be
    // final anymore, though you might leave it that way if you never
    // intend to replace the array with a different one.
    // Also recommend making that method (static or instance) a  private method.
    public class Numbers extends Alfabhto {
        public Numbers() {
            // Create this once and reuse it
            Random rand = new Random();

            // Note using <, not <=, on the loops
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                    pinakas[i][j] = rand.nextInt(38) - 12;
                    System.out.println(pinakas[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Since Numbers is an inner class, we need to be able to create instances of Alfabhto
    private Alfabhto() {
    }

    // We need something in Alfabhto to run the Numbers constructor    
    private void run() {
        // Run the code in the Numbers constructor
        new Numbers();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* None of this does anything, presumably you'll use it later...
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an alphanumeric combination");
        String fail = s.nextLine();
        */
        // Run our run method, which will run the code in the Numbers constructor
        new Alfabhto().run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider having `rand` a `static`, and synchronizing on it. `Random` is not thread-safe, and in its current form, it's still statistically anomalous across separate instances of `Numbers`.

Comment: @Bathsheba: `rand` is a local within the constructor, not shared between threads or instances.

Comment: Indeed, but separate `Numbers` instances will be correlated, and that's statistically incorrect.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Gotcha. Useful to know. Kind of advanced for this particular OP; I suspect they're creating a single instance (at most, so far the whole thing could just be static). :-)

Comment: Thank you, following your info I've modified it to the edited text above in the OP. I get an error on the print though :( I've tried many possible combinations but... It says "pinakas" cannot be referenced from static context, but if I define it in the class, another problem will occur in the method, even if it's flagged as final. I also must define i and j and frankly, don't know what to do there...

Answer (score -1):

In your main function, you never create an instance of Numbers so whatever your wrote in there is not being called. Once you create a new Numbers(), it should print something out.

Comment: You don't really "call" a class, you create an instance of it. Also, the syntax for creating an object is not like calling a function (`Numbers()`), you need to use the `new` keyword and do `new Numbers()`